# How resistors really works?

Tags: resistors, load

From what I've readed, a resistor is a component which limit the current in a circuit. Supposing that I've a load that is rated for 12v 500mA, if I put a resistor to limit the current to, for example, 100mA what will happen to the load that expect to draw more current? Will it drop more voltage?

Comment: The 12 V will be divided between the two loads. The voltage dropped across each will be proportional to the resistance. See _Ohm's Law_ and _potential divider_.

Comment: "a resistor is a component which limit the current in a circuit" That is true only under a very loose interpretation of "limit", and in some develishs circuits the relation might even be reversed.

Comment: "to limit the current to, for example, 100mA" now you are overinterpreting the term "reduce". A resistor does *not* reduce the current *to a specific value*. Cmpare to: I put a brake on the cyclists wheel to reduce its speed to 3 km/h (note that a simple brake will not do that). Now what happens when he hits a wall? Of course his speed will no longer be 3 km/h.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ohms law. V = I * R. If you reduce the current I through the load, you will have a proportional drop in voltage V. For simple resistive loads, inductive loads like motors are a bit more complex, but still a general rule of thumb.